# Getting VAT reimbursed when travelling out of Italy on a student visa

Tags: airports, tax-refunds

I am a student living in Italy and I'm planning to travel to my home country (Pakistan). I have made a purchase in Italy, is it possible to get the VAT reimbursed at Milan Malpensa airport when I am traveling back even if I am a student visa (temporary EU-resident) holder in Italy?

Comment: I'm from Pakistan, and my visa is valid till September'17

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think with a visa that long you will be considered a resident of the EU and as such not eligable for VAT reimbursement when you make visits home.